# Want to get list of friends when User Log in

Tags: facebook

I want to add a login button on my site such that when a user login to my site by accepting the permissions ,a list of his/her friends are available ..i have included a video that can tell you more exactly what i want please help me.and also tell me is it possible to get friends list without having a .php .I dont` know alot about this so explain me in simple language [VIDEO LINK](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtklKZzSDqQ)

Comment: This is not a good type of question for this site.  Questions here must be more  specific.  [Here is a link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) to the official software development kits that Facebook supports.  You can essentially use any programming language you feel comfortable with.   Why not do some reading, try come code out and come back to ask a more specific question about a problem you are having.  For now you are going to have to do some more research.

Comment: Sir i have just started using stackoverflow!May be i am not specific in text but i have attached a video link too.I just want how to get that.Thanks

Comment: With all due respect, Sir, we are not here to do the work for you.  try something yourself and if you come across a specific problem you can post about it here.  But asking - how to create an entire feature is not the correct way to go about it.  Break up your problem into parts - login, then fetching friends list, then rendering it into an HTML `select` element.  People will not do the work for you - you'll have to do some research too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the php version.  You can solely use the Javascript SDK to get a list of friends.

Once you have authenticated the user and the `FB.getLoginStatus()` returns that the user is logged in, then you can call

```
FB.api('me/friends',function(data){
  // do something with the data here
});
```